Is it possible to `git add` a subdirectory to the index as if it were the root directory?
I want to use an alternative index file to create a completely independent filesystem structure with an independent history in the same Git repo, in the flavor of git notes.
To make this easier, I would like to be able to take an arbitrary directory and git add it to an (alternate) index file and commit it as if it were the root of the working tree.
For example, suppose my directory structure is as follows:
.
└── subdir
    └── hello.txt

1 directory, 1 file

If I were to run git add subdir normally, my index would look like this:
git ls-files -s
100644 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad 0   subdir/hello.txt

Instead, I want my index to look like this:
git ls-files -s
100644 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad 0   hello.txt

Is there an existing mechanism in git to add a user-specified directory to the index file as if it were the root directory, or is my only option to use plumbing commands like update-index to manually add each file to the index at the appropriate (relative) path?

You could make it a submodule. It would be its own repo and thus have its own root and its own history. But at the same time, it would be a subdir of your primary repo

Yes, you can certainly do this. GIT_INDEX_FILE in the environment specifies your custom manifest, and a custom work tree root is common enough there's an option for it, --work-tree, which is more convenient for one-offs than the GIT_WORK_TREE override.  So to commit an arbitrary path to say refs/sideband/merlin you'd
( export GIT_INDEX_FILE=`git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`/merlin.index
  myref=refs/sideband/merlin
  parent=`git rev-parse -q --verify $myref`

  git --work-tree=path/to/anywhere add .
  git update-ref $myref $(
        git commit-tree ${parent:+-p $parent} -m 'hi' `git write-tree`
  )
)

edit: needed --absolute-git-dir

After you add subdir, you can create a tree object for it.
git write-tree --prefix=subdir

It creates a tree object that represents everything added inside subdir, and returns the hash of the object. Supppose it's 2e81171448eb9f2ee3821e3d447aa6b2fe3ddba1. And then you can create a commit from this tree, so that the tree is the root tree of the commit.
git commit-tree -m "commit message" 2e81171448eb9f2ee3821e3d447aa6b2fe3ddba1

You can also use one or more -p $parent_commit to specify parent commits for the new commit. The sequence of the multiple -p parameters is also the sequence of the parent commits of the created commit. It just creates a commit and does not update any ref or update the worktree.
Besides git write-tree, you can just run git commit to create a commit first, so that the tree object of subdir is created. To inspect the hash of a tree object in a revision,
git rev-parse $revision:$path
# for example, the tree hash of subdir in the current head
git rev-parse HEAD:subdir

After getting the tree hash, you can then use commit-tree to create a commit. In fact, you can directly use git commit-tree $revision:$path instead of getting the value of $revision:$path first.

As mentioned above you can wire your own tree with git porcelain commands.
Other option depending on your requirement's can be subtree or submodule.

I want to use an alternative index file to create a completely independent filesystem structure with an independent history in the same Git repo


git submodule will allow you to manage your "external" code in an external repository,
git subtree will let you manage a standalone branch (detached from your main branch)

But its not completely clear what you wish to do
